# Проблема с доступом к const внутри класса

Tags: javascript

В конструкторе класса объявлена константа

```
constructor(gSel){

    const hodXthis = this.hodX.bind(this);

    this.gameSel = document.getElementById(gSel);
    this.gameSel.addEventListener("click", hodXthis);
}
```

В методе этогоже класса пытаюсь получить к ней доступ

```
hodX(e){
                if(this.proverka("x")[0]) {
                    this.gameSel.removeEventListener("click", hodXthis);
                    alert("You (x) win!");
                }
}
```

Но в консоли получаю ошибку

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: hodXthis is not defined
    at krgame.hodX
```

Почему так происходит? Ведь по-идее я должен получать доступ к константе в любом месте класса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Почему так происходит? Ведь по-идее я должен получать доступ к константе в любом месте класса.

Это с чего это вы взяли? У конструктора и какого-то метода только одна общая вешь - контекст. Область видимости ( где и хранятся переменные ) разная. Хотите доступ в любом месте класс? Делайте переменную св-вом объекта

```
constructor(gSel){

  // нижнее подчеркивание намекает, что переменная приватная
  // это лишь соглашение, так как самих приватных св-во
  // в js пока не завезли(
  this._hodXthis = this.hodX.bind(this);

  this.gameSel = document.getElementById(gSel);
  this.gameSel.addEventListener("click", this._hodXthis);
}

hodX(e){
  if(this.proverka("x")[0]) {
    this.gameSel.removeEventListener("click", this._hodXthis);
    alert("You (x) win!");
  }
}
```

P.S.

```
if(this.proverka("x")[0]) {
```

За такое по рукам бьют, транслитом лучше переменные не называть. Можно назвать `checkGameStatus` или еще как-нибудь, но не как не `proverka`.